# How to make a projection submenuItem of a menuItem In Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I use Orchard CMS 1.10.1. When creating a projection from dashboard I can check `show on menu`to show it on root of my menu.

I was wondering how can it be placed as `subMenuItem` and not in the root of my menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding new menu items in Orchard, it will add them always to the root level, but after you add them go to `Navigation` page and sort the menu items as you want by dragging them.

FYI, you can drag an item to be child to other one.